# How to get the value of zlib.output_compression from php.ini

Tags: php, xampp, zlib

There has a config in **...\xampp\php\php.ini** file:

`zlib.output_compression=Off`

Can I get the value of this config in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: `echo ini_get("zlib.output_compression");`